# Configuring DHCP server

Tags: cisco, dhcp

I am playing around in my virtual environment and I would like to find out what is the best practise to configure DHCP server - configure it on the Router or Server running Windows Server or some type of Linux?

Comment: Depends on how you intend to use it and how many clients. But DHCP questions are off topic here. You can try asking on [sf].

Comment: Question is too broad

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about hosts, servers, VMs, applications, and protocols above OSI layer-4 are all off-topic, as are questions athat are too broad or lead to primarily opinion-based answers, or product or resource recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendations are:

- **Small environment with good router** If you have a reasonably small, reasonably static, environment with a very stable router, put it on the router.  This device is already a single point of failure on your network.
- **Medium scale network / uptime critical** If uptime is critical, use multiple DHCP servers on dedicated devices; just like you'll have multiple routers with HSRP or good host routing.  Normally I'd recommend FreeBSD/Linux/Similar.  Either have co-operating configuration (so each server knows about the other) or racing non-overlapping configuration (each server gives out half the address space).  Personally I like the latter approach as it's very simple.
- **Global network** Typically has a set of DHCP servers per region, with DHCP forwarding on the local network routers.

I am strongly in favour of putting your static devices in the DHCP too, with bootp "reservations" or whatever your DHCP software calls them (so they get the same address indefinitely).  That way you have a single source of the addressing.

My recommendation would be against DHCP on your Windows servers unless you have overriding personnel or policy reasons to do it, but certainly it works fine if you want to use it.

In general, DHCP is considered out of remit here, but it is nonetheless an important feature of your network design.